# PySpark Dataframe: Changing two Columns at the same time based on condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I was wondering if there is a way to change two (or more) columns of a PySpark Dataframe at the same time.  Right now I am using `withColumn` but I don't know whether that means the condition will be checked twice (which my be too expensive for a large dataframe).  This code basically check for values in other two columns (for the same row) and based on that it changes  two columns to None/null.

```
   condition =  is_special_id_udf(col("id"))) & should_hide_response_udf(col("response_created"))


     new_df = df.withColumn(
            "response_text",
            when(condition, None)
            .otherwise(col("response_text"))
        )

     new_df = df.withColumn(
            "response_created",
            when(condition, None)
            .otherwise(col("response_created"))
        )
```

Comment: please share full code and example data. your code is not reproducible.

Comment: do you really need the data? The code is working as expected I am just wondering if a better way to do the same thing.

Comment: you are creating the same column twice, is your question how to do that?

Comment: That was a type in  the source code. I corrected it. I modified two different columns based on the same conditions. Right now I do that one after the other. I was wondering if there was a better way using either DF API or RDD. Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about adding to columns to the same dataframe or two different dataframes (your code would just end up having one new column as you take the original dataframe). Also you are using a condition which needs response_created, your goal is to overwrite it?

Comment: So basically I want to set to null the columns  "response_created" and "response_text" if conditions is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you can simply add the UDF as a new column, use it for calculations and drop it:

```
condition =  is_special_id_udf(col("id"))) & should_hide_response_udf(col("response_created"))

 new_df = df.withColumn("tmp", condition).withColumn(
        "response_text",
        when(col("tmp"), None)
        .otherwise(col("response_text"))
    ).withColumn(
        "response_created",
        when(col("tmp"), None)
        .otherwise(col("response_created"))
    ).drop("tmp")
```

If you really want to generate two columns then you can do create a struct column and flatten it (of course add columns you need to the select):

```
new_df = df.withColumn(
        "myStruct",
        when(condition, None)
        .otherwise(struct(col("response_text"), col("response_created")))
    ).select("myStruct.*")
```

Comment: second option is quite nice, makes my answer obsolete.

Comment: I think the first part of the answer is what I was looking, I wonder if there's a way without creating a column with the condition result but it looks cleaner.